# Clearing development files from device?

Tags: android, cordova, extjs

I'm developing with `Phonegap+Sencha` and decided to compile the example apps to test out speed.

Anyway because I compiled with the whole library in there the app ended up being about `30mb`. I'm not sure how far it got but then my computer crashed for a different reason before it finished.

I now have `128kb` free on my phone previously having `23mb` but no new apps or caches I seem to be able to clear.

How can I reclaim the space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy, and unpleasant answer is to try a factory reset.

Another option is to use a file explorer app or the DDMS tab in Eclipse to see what files are actually present on the device that you may not see in your app manager list. You may need to be rooted for this to work.

It also wouldn't hurt, if you haven't already, to turn off the phone, pull the battery, put the battery in and turn on the phone and see if anything changed.

Comment: Im really reluctant to factory reset though it has already crossed my mind. Thanks for the DDMS suggestion at least I can now access the internal memory.. sadly I can't find a folder named anything like devCache. Any more ideas about where this data might be hidden? (also have tried removing battery and power cycling to no avail)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not the most knowledgeable in this area, but off the top of my head, check the internal memory and see what directories you can find that have been modified recently and/or are such a large size.